# addition not working in for-loop verilog

Tags: for-loop, verilog, addition, vivado

I am trying to write a Verilog code that will multiply two floating point numbers.  trying to multiply to two mantissa by shifting and adding is where I am running into troubles.  The problem is that when I try and update the "shift and add" variable,C_m_tmp, nothing happens (C_m_tmp = C_m_tmp + tmp;).  I have omitted any blocks of code that are not relevant to my problem.  Can anyone tell me were I am going wrong?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module float_mult( A_m, B_m, C_m);
    input [22:0]A_m, B_m;
    output [45:0]C_m;

    reg [45:0] C_m_tmp;
    reg [22:0] A_m_tmp;
    reg [22:0] B_m_tmp;
    reg [45:0] tmp;
    reg [4:0]i;

    initial begin         
        assign C_m_tmp = 46'b0;
    end
 //need to remove the leading one from mantissas
always@ (A_m) begin
    A_m_tmp = A_m >> 1;
    A_m_tmp = A_m_tmp ^ 23'b10000000000000000000000;
end
always@ (B_m) begin
    B_m_tmp = B_m >> 1;
    B_m_tmp = B_m_tmp ^ 23'b10000000000000000000000;
 end
 always@(A_m_tmp, B_m_tmp) begin
    for (i=0; i <=22; i=i+1)
        if (B_m_tmp[i] == 1)begin
            tmp =  {23'b0,A_m_tmp};
            tmp = tmp <<i;
            C_m_tmp = C_m_tmp + tmp;    //this line does nothing
        end
 end
    always@(C_m_tmp)begin
        if (C_m_tmp[45] == 1) begin
            C_e_tmp = C_e_tmp + 1'b1;
        end

    end


    assign C_e = C_e_tmp + 8'b01111111;
    assign C_m = C_m_tmp[45:23];
    assign C_s = C_s_tmp;        

endmodule
```

Comment: Get rid of the `assign` within the initial block

Comment: Use `always@*` or `always_comb` instead of manual sensitivity list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
initial begin         
assign C_m_tmp = 46'b0;
end
```

there is no need of the above code.

Instead, you can do

```
always@(C_m_tmp)begin
C_m_tmp = 'b0;
        if (C_m_tmp[45] == 1) begin
            C_e_tmp = C_e_tmp + 1'b1;
        end

    end
```

Comment: I had to initialize C_m_tmp in a different block but it WAS the initial block that was messing up the code.  Thank you very much.